# how to get index of particular item in listview wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, indexing

I want Index of particular item in a listview
for example  **ListViewItem  Index**

```
         Apple            0
         Ball             1
         Cat              2
         Dog              3
```

if i pass "Cat" as an item it should return index of Cat As "3"

Comment: searching for an index like this should have some knowledge about the underlying data item. It would be easier, although theoretically we can use `ToString` on the object item to get the string representation but it's not safe, because the actual displayed string can be selected using ItemTemplate, ...

Answer (score 1):

Finally Solution Here:
int index = MyListView.Items.IndexOf("Cat");

Comment: If this is your solution, your question is wrong. You do not work with ListViewItems. With ListViewItems your solution could not work. Proof: `string test = (new ListViewItem() { Content = "Apple" }).ToString();`. But good you found a solution!

Answer (score 0):

`ListView` Items are contained in its `ItemSource`which is an `IEnumerable`

You can get the Index of somthing by doing: (assuming that your List above is a List< string >)

`(myListView.ItemSource as List<String>).IndexOf("Cat");`

However, i would highly recommend that you look into how MVVM Works when building a WPF application, lots of information and tutorials can be found using Google.

Answer (score -1):

I think SelectedInex of the ListView-control is what you are looking for. Take a look at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedindex(v=vs.110).aspx

My sample code:

```
    // Assuming that this is your control
    ListView yourControl = new ListView();

    yourControl.Items.Add(new ListViewItem() { Content = "Apple" });
    yourControl.Items.Add(new ListViewItem() { Content = "Ball" });
    yourControl.Items.Add(new ListViewItem() { Content = "Cat" });
    yourControl.Items.Add(new ListViewItem() { Content = "Dog" });

    // get your index
    var newList = yourControl.Items.OfType<ListViewItem>().Select(Item => Item.Content.ToString()).ToList();
    int catIndex = newList.IndexOf("Cat"); // <-- your index
```

Comment: not a selected index  i want index of a particular item "Cat" in a listview

Comment: Ok, I make an example.

Comment: @shubh i added a solution. But it depends on how you fill your data.